# scala integration tests "No such setting/task"

Tags: scala, integration-testing, scalatest

Integration test configuration is new to me.

I cannot get my scalatest integration tests to run (on sbt or intellij).

My unittests in `src/test/scala` run fine.

My integration tests are in `src/it/scala`

If I run with `sbt it:test` the error is  "No such setting/task"

If I run on intellij (i.e., with the 'run' button), I get

```
Unable to load a Suite class. This could be due to an error in your runpath. Missing class: xxx.tools.es_ingester.EsIntegrationSpec
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxx.tools.es_ingester.ConfluenceEsIntegrationSpec
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
```

The class, however, is clearly in `/src/it/scala/xxx/tools/es_ingester`.

**update: build.sbt**

```
name := "xxx.tools.data_extractor"

version := "0.1"

organization := "xxx.tools"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

sbtVersion := "1.2.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.5"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "1.2.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.25"
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.11.2"
libraryDependencies += "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk15on" % "1.61"
libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.24.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-client" % "6.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "6.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % "6.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.11.3"
```

Comment: Could you please show your build.sbt?

Comment: Updated :) Thanks a million for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added configuration for integration test.

For example, adding `it` in scala test or default settings etc.

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "it, test"
```

For all integration, settings [refer](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html)

I hope, it will help.